# How to insert HTML tags in JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert an HTML link into a variable array with multiple strings, but the advice I've seen in other posts hasn't worked for me.

So, I define within a `<script>` tag a variable with 4 text strings like this:

```
<script>
var btnTxt = ["blah blah blah", "blah-blah-blah", "blah blah", "blah"];
</script>
```

When someone clicks on one of 4 image buttons, the text that is currently visible gets switched out to the new text. e.g., if the text "blah blah" is displaying & you click on button 4, you now see "blah".

What I want is to take, say, "blah blah blah" and turn the middle "blah" into a link. So, essentially `"blah <a href=http://example.com>blah</a> blah"`. I followed encoding advice like &lt; or < but the best I got was visibly seeing the "a" tag in the text, not seeing the link.

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code you have for inserting the modified HTML into the document, the button click handler.

Comment: Could you edit your question, and add that code in there?

Comment: Got it figured out. Thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: I don't see the link with what you have, and what you want. Where do you get the link from? How do you determine where to insert the hyperlink? What is the logic? Your question is lacking clarity.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are trying to do? I hope this helps :)

```
     <script>
        var btnTxt=["<a href=http://www.blah.com>blah</a>","<a href=http://www.blah.com>blah</a>","<a href=http://www.blah.com>blah</a>"];

        btn4.addEventListener('click',function(){
        //assuming you already have div
        div.innerHTML="blah blah"+btnTxt[1];
        }
        </script>

        //another option
        <style>
        a{text-decoration:none}
        a:hover{text-decoration:none}
        <style>
        <p>blah, blah, <a id="blah" href="#">blah</a></p>
        <script>
        btn4.addEventListener('click',function(){
        //assuming you already have id blah
        blah.attribute="http://www.blah.com";
        blah.style.color='orange';//if you want css to define the link once it becomes available. 

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Your comments helped me figure it out. I was able to simply concatenate within the string itself using the + symbol. I swear I tried that earlier but it's working now and I understand multiple ways of addressing it for the future. Thanks again.